# Exclude one directory from trac environment

Tags: apache, trac

I'm using a webserver for trac only, so I have this conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName intranet.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/Intranet/www"
  IndexIgnore /tmp
  SetEnv trac.env_parent_dir "D:/Intranet/www/"

  RedirectMatch ^(/)?$ /knowledge/wiki
  RedirectMatch ^/([^/]+)/trac/?(.*)$ /$1/$2
  RedirectMatch ^/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/wiki

  <Location "/Proj1/">
    ...
  </Location>
  <Location "/Proj2/">
    ...
  </Location>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to create a new folder where a non-trac site will appear. I created a folder in "D:/Intranet/www/test". When I load the site in "http://intranet/test" the following message appears:

```
Trac Error

TracError: No Trac environment found at d:\intranet\www\test
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:\\intranet\\www\\test\\VERSION'
```

How could I exclude test folder from trac-environment or prevent trac to try find an environment in that folder?

Comment: Could you just put all of your Trac environments in `D:/Intranet/www/trac` and change the directive to `SetEnv trac.env_parent_dir "D:/Intranet/www/trac"`?